# Remove entry from JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

I have a Python application where the user can insert a name and one or more extensions, the final result looks like this:

```
{
"sets": [
{
  "name": "first",
  "extensions": ".exe"
},
{
  "name": "second",
  "extensions": [
    ".pdf",
    ".epub"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "third",
  "extensions": [
    ".mp3",
    ".mp4",
    ".wav"
  ]
}
]
}
```

I want to delete the entry with the name "third", and consequently the correspondent "extensions".

I have tried something like this:

```
def deleteJson():
    lines = []
    with open("sets.json","r") as json_file:
        for line in json_file.readlines():
            j = json.loads(line)
            if not j['name'] == "third":
               lines.append(line)
    with open("sets.json",'w') as json_file:
        json_file.writelines(join(lines))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `json` library instead:

```
import json

with open('sets.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data['sets'] = [sub for sub in data['sets'] if sub['name'] != 'third']

with open('sets.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```